# How can I customize the data: :confirm popup to prompt for an input, that will be appended to the request params?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

Many places in my application, submitting forms and visiting post-links requires the user to specify some reasoning as to why they decided to do so (the comments/reasoning are used to track who did what changes internally).

Now for this reason, I would like to be able to change the behaviour of `data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to submit this form?"}` to prompt for an input instead of just answering yes/cancel. I would like the box to appear with a an input field, which content will then be appended to the requests params, so I can store it from the controller.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try some modal service like bootstrap modal, or just build your own directive. there's some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824984/custom-confirm-dialog-with-javascript). essentially whatever func you tie your ng-click to will call `$modalService` first, and once user confirms/denies, $modalService will call `func.success` or `func.error`

Comment: this looks perfect! good find too... i helped out with a similar modal q in [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547476/show-modal-after-form-submission-untill-next-page-loads-does-not-work-on-safa/36739727#36739727). let me know what worked

Answer (score 1):

Use fake submit button which is trigger prompt dialog.
When prompt is filled, copy the value intu form hidden input, then trigger form submit event.
This is the working example:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked />
    <input id="myVisibleInput" name="visibleinput" type="text" />  
    <input id="myHiddenInput" name="hiddeninput" type="text" />
    <button id="fakesubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#fakesubmit').on('click', function() {
    var answer = prompt('Why?');
    if (answer != null) {
        $('#myHiddenInput').val(answer);
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});

$("#myForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).serialize());
});
```

CSS:

```
#myHiddenInput {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prompt:

```js
var test = prompt("Enter your name:");
alert("Hi " + test + "!");
```

[Prompt - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)